# Detecting Missing Method

Tags: c#, .net

Assume I have 2 dlls maintained by 2 different teams:

**Team1.dll (v1.0)**

```
public class Foo
{
    int GetValue() { return 3; }
}
```

**Team2.dll (v1.0)**

```
public class Bar
{
    public int IncFooValue(Foo foo) { return foo.GetValue() + 1; }
}
```

When Team1.dll (v1.0) and Team2.dll (v1.0) are executed, everything is fine. But assume that Team1.dll were changed & the method `Foo.GetValue()` were removed (v1.1) and dropped next to Team2.dll (all without rebuilding Team2.dll). If executed, then you would get a MissingMethodException.

***Question:*** How could I detect if Team1.dll is no longer compatible with Team2.dll without executing them?

For example, something like:

```
Foreach Class in Team2.dll
    Foreach Method in Class
        Foreach Instruction in Method
            If Instruction not exists in Team1.dll
                Throw "Does not exist"
```

Comment: you should be using semantic versioning. removing a method is a breaking change.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when they are not compatible, an error or a change in strategy (fallback)?

Comment: @DanielA.White: I agree, but this isn't about version numbering. Just trying to detect if a breaking change occurred without rebuilding

Comment: @alexm: Error is fine. I'm actually looking for a way for an external tool to detect if 2 assemblies are compatible. (I'll update the question to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the type contains the definition of the method.

```cs
if (foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetValue") != null)
{
    return foo.GetValue() + 1;
}
```

as others have suggested you may be better off pursuing another strategy (better versioning/backwards compatibility or handling the exception on the calling end.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually looking for a more generic way to detect if Test1.dll is compatible with Test2.dll. For example, code I could put into a tool to run on Test2.dll to detect if all the methods called exist in Test1.dll...

Comment: Have a read of http://semver.org/  Look at following the ideas in that and just get your code to check the version of the other dll on application startup

Comment: I'm actually looking for a technical solution rather than one relying on conventions. There's a couple of issues with relying on semver: 1) people make mistakes, 2) at large corporations version numbers are sometimes decided by bureaucrats.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to detect missing methods by forcing JIT compilation of your methods.

For that you just need enumerate all methods in your assemblies using reflection and then call `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle)` for each of them.

The tricky part here is dealing with generics. If your method or class contains generics, you also need to specify the concrete types for which your generic method will be jitted:

```
Type[] classGenericArgs = ...;
Type[] methodGenericArgs = ...;
Type[] allGenericArgs = classGenericArgs.Concat(methodGenericArgs).ToArray();
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle, allGenericArgs.Select(p => p.TypeHandle).ToArray());`
```

If your generic arguments also have constraints, you need to make sure that the types you choose satisfy these constraints, otherwise, jitting will fail.

Satisfying constraints can be difficult, so I wrote a Jitter class to automate this. It forces load of all libraries referenced by your application into memory and runs jitting with automatically substituting appropriate concrete classes for your generic methods (if possible). The usage for it is simple, just specify which assemblies you want jitted:

```
Jitter.RunJitting(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("My.Company.Namespace"));
```

Make sure your .NET app references all assemblies you want to verify.

You can find the source code for Jitter [here](https://github.com/oleksiizamyslov/samples/blob/main/Jitter.cs). It is far from perfect, but is able to jit 99.8% of all methods in our codebase and detect broken package dependencies for us.

Comment: is this "Jitter" advertising? when you remove API, you declare/announce breaking changes to the consumers of your DLLs

Comment: This helps automating detection of broken dependencies when you are a consumer.